# Python FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python

I am trying to open all the '*.json' files in a directory and get some data out of them

```
import json
import os #os module imported here
import glob

path = 'C:\Saba\Python Workspace'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith('.json'):
        with open(filename,'r') as f:
            data = json.load(filename)
            print(data['key'],end="*")
            for path in data['paths']:
                print(path['method'],end="*")
                for resources in path['resources']:
                    print(resources['key'],end="*")

print("\b"+"$")
```

**This is the Error i get :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Saba/Python Workspace/folder.py", line 9, in <module>
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'order-securityTransferOrders-service-v1.0.0-inventory.json'
```

Comment: Try: print (filename) after your IF condition and comment everything under it and check the output of that.

Answer (score 1):

You are running the script in different path. Adding the absolute path of the filename will do the trick.

```
import os.path
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    abs_file_path = os.path.abspath(filename)
    if filename.endswith('.json'):
        with open(abs_file_path,'r') as f:
        # your code ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you run this script ? Python tries to search for your Json file in the current script folder.

If you want Python to find within the given path, you should write somthin like :

```
with open(os.path.join(path,filename) ,'r') as f:
```

Comment: Thanks, changed my worksapace in Visual Studio and copied the code there. The error no longer exists

Answer (score 0):

replace line ***`with open(filename,'r') as f:`*** with ***`with open(os.path.abspath(filename),'r') as f:`***